# How to prove the Rayleigh-quotient problem for p-norm is convex?

Tags: functions

I don't know how to prove the problem f(x)=\sum_ij (W_ij * abs(x_i - x_j)^p)/\sum_i abs(x_i)^p is convex? I wonder if anybody can help me,thanks!

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset maths in questions. Please also add more details so you question is viewed favourably: where did the question come from? What have you already tried? What is the definition of $W_{ij}$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.